# Test example in unofficial axis2/c

Tags: c, web-services, apache-axis, axis2c

Hello i would like to ask a question regarding the unofficial axis2/c.

I installed the latest release and tried to run the example "ExampleJsonEchoClient" (found in https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/wiki/ExampleJsonEchoClient)
While a page loads in localhost, with a check button, there is no response when clicking on it.

In the guide provided in the same page there is this step: "Download jquery into that dir and name it jquery.js" and provides a link to :http://jquery.com/download/

Which version should i download? and should i name the whole folder jquery.js? Or use a file in the folder named jquery?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** 
Thanks! This worked!

Weirdly i now have an installation problem when trying to install axis2/c unofficial to a second computer

i followed the instructions but get the following error message

```
json/axis2_json_writer.c: In function 'axis2_json_writer_get_json_string':
json/axis2_json_writer.c:173:64: error: 'JSON_C_TO_STRING_PLAIN' undeclared
(first use in this function)
json/axis2_json_writer.c:173:64: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[7]: *** [axis2_json_writer.lo] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/.../axis2c-unofficial/src/core/transport/http/sender'
make[6]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/.../axis2c-unofficial/src/core/transport/http/sender'
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/.../axis2c-unofficial/src/core/transport/http'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/.../axis2c-unofficial/src/core/transport'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/.../axis2c-unofficial/src/core'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/./axis2c-unofficial/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/.../axis2c-unofficial'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I cannot figure this out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any directory structure, but `echo.html` expects `jquery.js` and `echo.js` in the same directory as `echo.html`.

That paths can be easily changed in `echo.html`, but in the example directory structure is plain, i.e. all the files (`echo.html`, `jquery.js` and `echo.js`) are inside `/var/www/json-echo/` directory.

```
/var/www/json-echo/
                echo.html
                echo.js
                jquery.js
```

---

To work with JSON you can use any modern version of jQuery (1.x or 2.x), compressed or uncompressed, for your flavor. After you download `jquery-x.xx.x(.min).js` rename it into `jquery.js` (or edit `echo.html`).

As written on jquery.org/download site there is no specific differences between versions 1.x and 2.x except Internet Explorer support:

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: thanks for the reply! it worked,but i edited the original as now i face another issue

Comment: Possibly, you forgot to install json-c from github or you have two versions of json-c (1. which comes with OS and installed, 2. installed from source code). Try to remove system devel packet (e.g: `sudo apt-get remove libjson0-dev`).